# reading docker volume in docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a simple `nginx`contianer to serve documentation that is autogenerated (from an azure build agent on the server The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  internal_routing:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - type: bind
        source: /path/to/docs/generated/by/sphinx
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html/docs/ASAP      
        read_only: true 
      - type: bind
        source: ./files # inted.html style.css etc
        target: /usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

This works great when `docker-compose up` is run after the files were created. However, once the build agent runs, the mounted directory appear empty on the `internal routing` app, while the `/path/to/docs/generated/by/sphinx` countains the correct `html` files. Taking the `internal routing` app down and up again, resoles this. This is not a great solution though as it should become part of our CI/CD and there are many different projects waiting to be added.

Will an external docker volume fix this (I've tried and failed)?